# Looking for a cheap(ish) micromouse that I can program with C/C++

Tags: arduino, mobile-robot, wheeled-robot, micromouse

I'm looking to buy a micromouse (i.e. a small single-board unit with wheels and IR sensors that can move around freely). I've done a lot of searching but have only found resources relating to building one from components bought separately. However, I'm more of a programmer than an electrician so I fear I would struggle with this.

Anybody know where to buy one of these in the UK? (PICAXE does some suitable stuff but they're BASIC only unfortunately). My budget is about £60.

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* Jazcash, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a [Pololu 3Pi](http://www.pololu.com/product/975). They were going for 50usd during black friday. Normally $99.  You can use arduino IDE to program it using Wiring, a C/C++ like language.

You would probably have to add IR sensors yourself, either via the expansion board, or re-wire the existing line detectors

At the moment, Hobby Robots are still only reachable by those with soldering skills. But that will be changing in the next few years.

[image: 3Pi]

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be hard-pressed to find a Micromouse off the shelf besides PICAXE.  If you want one that's a bit more advanced, I'd recommend putting the robot together yourself.  I would encourage you to try out the electronics on a project like this, they aren't too bad to figure out and there are lots of resources online.

Some recommendations:

- An arduino-nano is capable for such a task, look into AVR-GCC for programming.
- NEMA-17 sized stepper motors will supply enough power, Pololu is a good site to find these motors and matching wheels/controllers.
- I've seen people use Sharp IR's before, this will simplify some of the electronics.

This is a difficult project but very rewarding!  Best of luck.

Comment: Might try building one then. There are indeed a lot of resources out there to help, but I have absolutely no experience with electronics so it's quite a scary thing to look into when most the articles I've read are very jargony and over-my-head technical.